# Write statement cannot produce new lines within user-defined formatted I/O procedures for derived type

Tags: io, fortran, newline, derived-types, formatted

I want to implement the user-defined I/O procedures for the derived types in my Fortran code. However, `write` statements within those procedures cannot produce new lines between two sequential `write` statements. The derived type and procedures are defined as below.

**The module:**

```
module station_module
    implicit none

    character(8), parameter :: FmtFloat = '(5E15.7)'

    type :: station
        integer, private :: ns = 0
        real, public, allocatable :: xloc(:), yloc(:), zloc(:)
    contains
        procedure, public :: import_station
        procedure, public :: export_station
        procedure, private :: read_station
        generic, public :: read (formatted) => read_station
        procedure, private :: write_station
        generic, public :: write (formatted) => write_station
        final :: destruct_station
    end type station

    interface station
        module procedure new_station
    end interface station

contains

    function new_station(n) result(t)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        type(station) :: t

        if (n > 0) then
            allocate (t%zloc(n))
            allocate (t%yloc(n))
            allocate (t%xloc(n))
            t%ns = n
        end if
    end function new_station

    subroutine read_station(dtv, unit, iotype, vlist, iostat, iomsg)
        implicit none
        class(station), intent(inout) :: dtv
        integer, intent(in) :: unit
        character(*), intent(in) :: iotype
        integer, intent(in) :: vlist(:)
        integer, intent(out) :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        call dtv%import_station(unit)

        iostat = 0
    end subroutine read_station

    subroutine import_station(this, unit)
        implicit none
        class(station), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: unit
        character(256) :: header, footer
        integer ns

        read (unit, '(A)') header !> Header
        read (unit, *) ns
        if (ns > 0) then
            if (allocated(this%zloc)) then
                deallocate (this%zloc)
            end if
            allocate (this%zloc(ns))
            read (unit, *) this%zloc

            if (allocated(this%yloc)) then
                deallocate (this%yloc)
            end if
            allocate (this%yloc(ns))
            read (unit, *) this%yloc

            if (allocated(this%xloc)) then
                deallocate (this%xloc)
            end if
            allocate (this%xloc(ns))
            read (unit, *) this%xloc

            this%ns = ns
        end if
        read (unit, '(A)') footer !> Footer
    end subroutine import_station

    subroutine export_station(this, unit)
        implicit none
        class(station), intent(in) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: unit

        write (unit, '(A)') ">STATION INFO"
        write (unit, '(I6)') this%ns
        write (unit, *) "Z:"
        write (unit, FmtFloat) this%zloc
        write (unit, *) "Y:"
        write (unit, FmtFloat) this%yloc
        write (unit, *) "X:"
        write (unit, FmtFloat) this%xloc
        write (unit, '(A)') ">END STATION"
    end subroutine export_station

    subroutine write_station(dtv, unit, iotype, vlist, iostat, iomsg)
        implicit none
        class(station), intent(in) :: dtv
        integer, intent(in) :: unit
        character(*), intent(in) :: iotype
        integer, intent(in) :: vlist(:)
        integer, intent(out) :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        call dtv%export_station(unit)

        iostat = 0
    end subroutine write_station

    subroutine destruct_station(this)
        implicit none
        type(station), intent(inout) :: this

        if (allocated(this%xloc)) then
            deallocate (this%xloc)
        end if
        if (allocated(this%yloc)) then
            deallocate (this%yloc)
        end if
        if (allocated(this%zloc)) then
            deallocate (this%zloc)
        end if
        this%ns = 0
    end subroutine destruct_station

end module station_module
```

We can see that the user-defined **formatted write** statement just call a regular subroutine named `export_station`, by which I expect the same result in both ways.

Here is my **test program:**

```
program Test
    use station_module
    implicit none
    type(station) :: pt, pt1, pt2

    pt = station(4)

    write(*, *) pt

    call pt%export_station(6)

end program Test
```

**The output:**

```
 >STATION INFO     4Z:  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
 Y:  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00X:  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00>END STATION
>STATION INFO
     4
 Z:
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
 Y:
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
 X:
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
>END STATION
```

The regular subroutine `export_station` produces what I expect. New lines are produced between two `write` statements, while `write` statement of the derived type does not.

Answer (score 6):

This was also asked on the Intel forum. I replied there."User-defined derived-type I/O is all non-advancing (and you can't change this). If you want newlines you have to write them explicitly (using a / format, for example.)"

Comment: Just to make this more explicit: something like `WRITE(unit,'(a/)')` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There are two classes of output statements here: a parent and a child.  The parent output statement in the first case is the `write (*,*) pt`.

When this first is the parent, then the call to `export_station` through `write_station` leads to the write statements there being child output statements.  When `export_station` is called directly by the user those write statements are themselves parent output statements.

One significant difference between a child data transfer statement and a parent data transfer statement is that a parent statement positions the file prior to and after data transfer.  That is, when the `write (unit,*) "Z:"` completes the file is positioned after the record just written only when the transfer statement is a parent.

Thus, you see the new lines: this is simply placing after the written record.

A child data transfer statement, not positioning the file on completion, does not effect a new line.

---

I don't have access to a test machine at the moment, so this part is speculative.  You can explicitly write a new line character returned from `new_line('')` as part of your output for the child transfer statement.  As `advance='no'` will be ignored in a child statement you could use that for both cases, explicitly controlling where new lines are written, rather than relying on the split record approach as currently exists.

Comment: This was also asked on the Intel forum. I replied there."User-defined derived-type I/O is all non-advancing (and you can't change this). If you want newlines you have to write them explicitly (using a / format, for example.)"

Comment: A more concise statement which is probably worth being an answer more than a comment here, @stevelionel.

Comment: Your answer was correct, so I didn't want to step on your toes, but if you're ok with it... done!

Comment: Just because I'm right doesn't mean I explained it well ;). But seriously, too few technical Fortran questions have multiple explanations.